# Работа с длинными числами

Tags: библиотеки, числа

Какие есть библиотекки и на каких языках можно организовать арифметические действия с очень большими числами?

Comment: Что значит библиотеки?
Что значит большие числа?
На любом языке можно написать если включить чуть-чуть мозги. берете любое число и разлажевайте его в массив поразрядно что еще Вам нужно?

Comment: @SoftR, у меня профессиональная этика сейчас борется с желанием порядка на хэшкоде) Допишите хоть пару примеров что ли)

Comment: слышал, что, например, в Java есть класс, предназначенный для работы с числами, которые не входят в диапазоны стандартных типов. А разложить число в массив поочередно я и так могу

Comment: Допишите в метки язык(-и)

Comment: Павел, <a href="www.google.ru/search?q=java+biginteger">bigInt в java</a>

Comment: @Sh4dow
 Я не против добавить код на Delphi, но вопрос задан настолько размыто, что о чем писать даже не знаю.
Одно дело если ему нужно огромное целое число, совсем другое дело если нужно очень большая точность после запятой.

На счет порядка на hashcode я Вас полностью понимаю, нужно как то изначально заставлять вопрошающих ставить вопросы развернуто, а то вопрошающие думают что отвечающие телепаты.

Comment: Так а смысл писать ответ на неконкретный вопрос?) Вы же все равно не ответите так как надо, а де факто сообщение ответом не является (нарушение формата форума). Такие уточнения пишут в комментарии.

Comment: Не, в вопросе же и стоит «и на каких языках.» Возможно, человек язык подбирает под задачу. Или еще по какой-либо причине обзор хочет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Организовать, очевидно, можно на любых Тьюринг-полных языках.

Вот, набросал список некоторых примеров широко применяемых готовых решений для длинной арифметики по языкам. В основном, касательно целочисленной арифметики.

- C, C++ — библиотека [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/)
- Common Lisp — [не ограничивает](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node17.html) разрядность целых чисел
- Erlang — встроенный численный тип ([`integer()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id182862))
- Go — типы `Int` и `Rat` из библиотеки [`big`](http://golang.org/pkg/big/).
- Haskell — встроенный тип [`Integer`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Integer)
- Java — класс [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)
- OCaml — библиотека [`num`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual036.html)
- Pascal/Delphi — библиотека [MPArith](http://home.netsurf.de/wolfgang.ehrhardt/mp_intro.html)
- Perl — модули [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) и [bigrat](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigrat.html)
- PHP — модуль [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)
- Python — встроенный тип [`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) (или `long` для Python 2)
- Ruby — тип [`Bignum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Bignum.html)
- Scala — класс [`BigInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/BigInt.html)
- Scheme — начиная с R<sup>5</sup>RS рекомендация, с R<sup>6</sup>RS — требование о неограниченности разрядности чисел (например, см. [документацию Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Integers.html))
- Языки .NET — класс [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (появился в .NET Framework 4.0)

Answer (score 3):

В Python целые числа не ограничены по длине.

```
>>> 2**1000
```

10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376L

Comment: а можно что-то подобное на С-образных языках сделать?

Comment: Уже несколько раз вчера/позавчера писал: Gnu MP. http://gmplib.org. Там и целые, и рациональные, и действительные.

Answer (score 0):

GCL - Gnu Common Lisp - длина числа ограничена размером оперативной памяти компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

- Haskell, тип Integer
- Perl, модуль BigInt